# Using PHP cURL, how to send GET/POST data to a server, then fetch contents of a text file AFTER this text file is created and populated?

Tags: php, http, session, curl, networking

The example given on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) uses the PHP cURL library and fetches homepage file's (index.php or index.html) contents from a remote server to our local server. Now this file already exists there when we send the request.

There is a twist in my story. I need to send some GET data to the remote server, where that GET data is used to send a request to yet another server, *the response of which is written to a text file on the remote server. I need to get the contents of this text file.*

The question is this: How do I get the contents of the text file after this text file transferred back to my local machine?

I am using the following function to send data to the remote server:

```
function CurlSendPostJson($url='http://remote-host-IP/curl-req.php',$datajson){   
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datajson);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($datajson)));
    return $result = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

On the remote end:

```
<?php
//curl-req.php:-

// GET JSON CONTENT FROM CURL
$jsonStr = file_get_contents("php://input"); //read the HTTP body.

if (!empty($jsonStr)) {
    $data = json_decode($jsonStr);

    //Code to send req to the third server and save response in text file in this machine. 
    //I NEED TO SEND BACK THE CONTENTS OF THIS TEXT FILE TO THE FIRST SERVER. 
}
```